# PHP For Each Loop-Not Generating Entries

Tags: php, foreach, html-table, associative-array

I am trying to Iterate over an Associative Array which has the following structure

Output from var_export($data)

```
     <?php
Harvest_Project::__set_state(array(
    '_root' => 'project',
    '_tasks' => array() ,
    '_convert' => true,
    '_values' => array(
        'id' => '10122036',
        'client-id' => '4861417',
        'name' => 'ABC',
        'code' => '',
        'active' => 'true',
        'billable' => 'true',
        'bill-by' => 'Project',
        'hourly-rate' => '145.0',
        'budget' => '70.0',
        'budget-by' => 'project',
        'notify-when-over-budget' => 'true',
        'over-budget-notification-percentage' => '80.0',
        'over-budget-notified-at' => '2016-09-24',
        'show-budget-to-all' => 'false',
        'created-at' => '2016-03-15T21:38:40Z',
        'updated-at' => '2016-05-31T23:19:58Z',
        'starts-on' => '',
        'ends-on' => '',
        'estimate' => '70.0',
        'estimate-by' => 'project',
        'hint-earliest-record-at' => '2016-03-16',
        'hint-latest-record-at' => '2016-08-11',
        'notes' => '',
        'cost-budget' => '',
        'cost-budget-include-expenses' => 'false',
    ) ,
))
```

This is the code which I wrote to Iterate over the Array

```
  <?php
$project_id=10122036;
$result=$api->getProject($project_id);
$data = $result->get( "data" );

echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr><td>Project Name</td>
    <td>Hourly Rate</td>
    </tr>";
        foreach($data as $key=>$fruit) {
                        ?>
                     <tr><td><?php echo $fruit->name;?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $fruit->{'hourly-rate'};?></td></tr>
        <?php }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

This code only creates the columns and for some reason does not generate the entries for each row in the table. Hence the resulting table is an Empty table.
Kindly suggest where I am going wrong.

**Update**

This code is for querying Harvest using the Harvest API. This is the PHP Wrapper Library [http://mdbitz.com/docs/harvest-api/](http://[http://mdbitz.com/docs/harvest-api/].) which contains relevant classes and methods. getProject($project id) is a method to retrieve  project details based on the project ID.

Comment: the $result dump is useles. you need to show what's in `$data`, since THAT is what you're looping on. we have no idea what `getProjects()` and `get()` do.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Try to open a new tr tag inside the foreach and put that echo's into td tags. :)

Comment: are you able to print the data with out table ?

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($fruit)` inside the `foreach` loop? could you add it to the OP?

Comment: @RavinderReddy No I am not able to print the data without the table.

Comment: @user3402248 I think you are missing one loop, could you add what I have ask for?

Comment: @ReynierPM It doesn't seem to return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added html table code.

```
$project_id='10122036';
$result=$api->getProject($project_id);
echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr><th>Project Name</th>
    <th>Hourly Rate</th></tr>";

if( $result->isSuccess() ) {
    $project = $result->data;?>

<tr><td><?php echo $project->get( "name" );?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $project->hourly-rate;?></td></tr>

<?php }else{?>
   <tr><td colspan="2">No data from API</td></tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to get a single project using api, Use the below code

```
$project_id='10122036';
$result=$api->getProject($project_id);
if( $result->isSuccess() ) {
    $project = $result->data;
    echo $project->get( "name" );
    echo $project->hourly-rate;
}else{
   echo "No data from API";
```

}

If you see the out put "No data from API", then there is not data returned from API

Comment: It prints ABC 145.0

Comment: Thats the data found in your array... isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: then display it in table.